# Calling methods with arrays in C++

Tags: c++, c, arrays, methods

My problem is that I have trouble calling the int `computePattern` method in int main(). I am able to use the `insertNumber` method. But i don't know how to use the `computePattern` method. The method is to compute the number of patterns and return the count. The pattern is that both adjacent numbers must be greater than 7. Hence, there are only 5 pairs to check as there are 10 numbers. For now the output is only the random arrays which worked, but I need to print out the number of patterns too. I need to use methods as it is required in the question.

```
int insertNumber(int b )
{
 int a = rand()%10+1;
 return a;
}
int computePattern(int* inArray, int size )
{
int patterns=0;
 for(int z=0;z<size;z=z+2)
 {
    if(inArray[z]+inArray[z+1]>7)
    {
        patterns ++ ;
    }
}
 return patterns;
}
int main()
{
int arrays[10];
srand(time(0));
for ( int b=0; b<10 ; b++)
{
 arrays[b]  = insertNumber(b);
}
cout << "Arrays";
for ( int c= 0; c<10; c++)
{
    cout << " " ;
    cout << arrays[c];
}
int patterns =computePattern(arrays,10);
cout<<endl;
cout << "Patterns" <<patterns;
}
```

Comment: Properly indented code would be nice.

Comment: I think you mean  for (int d=0; d<10; d+=2)

Comment: also, arrays is a different instance in each method.  You probably want that variable to be file-scope.  You could declare int arrays[10]; before any function descriptions

Comment: You are not passing your array to your function! It is checking with garbage value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have different arrays in main than in computePattern.  Just because they share a name doesn't mean they're the same variable.  Each one of them is function scope.  A better way is to pass in the address and size of the array.

```
int computePattern(int* inArray, int size)
{
    int patterns=0;
    for(int z=0; z<size-1; z+=2)
    {
        if((inArray[z] + inArray[z+1]) > 7)
        {
            patterns++;
        }
    }
    return patterns;
}
//... then in main...

int patterns=computePattern(arrays, 10);
cout << patterns;
```

Comment: by the way... as you have it, the computePattern function only checks every pair of side by side values.  It can find out when the 1st and 2nd values are above 7, but it won't find out when the 2nd and 3rd values add up above 7.

Answer (score 1):

The array in `computePattern` remains uninitialised. Ergo, it will contain random variables in the memory which will mess up your computational path.

You should maybe modify the function to `int computePattern(int z, int array[])`. Then pass the `array` from the main scope.

Comment: May want to mention that using the value of a uninitialized variable is undefined behavior.

Comment: Using pointers to send array to function (and `f(array[])` is just that, a pointer!) is not a good idea. Better would be array reference ( `f(int(&tab)[10])` ) and better yet would be `std::array` or `std::vector`.